# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION exception in Vectored Exception Handler

Tags: c++, assembly, exception

I have a Vectored Exception Handler that caught a EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION exception.

The Rip and exception address are an invalid address that that contains no executable code.

I need to find out where it tried to execute this invalid address from.

I checked the stack and it was unreliable. Sometimes saying that the last return address was a return from calling GetCurrentThreadId(), but that API has no calls or jumps opcodes so it couldn't have tried to execute from there.

A limitation is that I cannot step through the application using a debugger.

How can I find the previous instructions that were executed before the exception?

Comment: what target is this?  x86?

Comment: looks like stack corruption due to buffer overrun for some automatic local variable results in exception when control reaches end of function. Could you run some validation program like valgrind or Application Validator to try and catch such problem as it happens and not afterwards?

Comment: How about using fprintf/fflush at the top/bottom of suspect routines?  When it crashes, you can check your log file to see where you were, then add more log messages until you track it down.

Comment: @old_timer its x64

Comment: You can't step through the application _code_ with a debugger? If you can throw the application in a debugger and the exception can be triggered easily enough, you can pause the application in the debugger, throw a break point up, un pause, and step through until the exception happens ..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're working off a mistaken assumption. Access Violations can occur for basically three reasons. Either you are trying to read data from an invalid address, write data to an invalid address, or read an instruction from an invalid address.

In the first two cases, the Instruction Pointer is valid, and points to an instruction which has a memory operand. But your case is clearly the third, as the IP is invalid.

Now the problem is, how did the IP get corrupted? It almost certainly was a bad jump or branch instruction. But why would that be the *first* problematic instruction? You often have been executing bytes that weren't intended to be interpreted as instructions. And then it's also clear how the stack can be corrupted. Any of those bytes could have been a PUSH or POP instruction.

An x86 doesn't have a real "history of executed instructions"; the closest you get is the L1 cache content. And that's not realistically available.